# How do I get xargs to show me the command lines it's generating without running them?

Tags: xargs

A fair number of linux commands have a dry-run option that will show you what they're going to do without doing it. I see nothing in the xargs man page that does that and no obvious way to emulate it.

(my specific use case is troubleshooting long pipelines, though I'm sure there are others)

Am I missing something?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: If you do want to execute + **print each command** in advance, use `xargs -n1 --verbose`.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You may benefit from the `-p` or `-t` flags.

`xargs -p` or `xargs --interactive` will print out the command to be executed and then prompt for input (y/n) to confirm before executing the command.

```
% cat list
one
two
three

% ls
list

% cat list | xargs -p -I {} touch {}
touch one ?...y
touch two ?...n
touch three ?...y

% ls
list
one
three
```

`xargs -t` or `xargs --verbose` will print each command, then immediately execute it:

```
% cat list | xargs -t -I {} touch {}
touch one 
touch two 
touch three 

% ls
list
one
three
two
```

Comment: superb answer with both `-p` and `-t` options. excellent examples. thank you!

Comment: On mac BSD `xargs` the `--verbose` option isn't recognized, but `-t` works!

Comment: Agreed - Great answer.  One tweak I might suggest, though.  While it's good to know the `-I {}` option for more complicated cases, it probably over-complicates that example slightly.  More concise would be to use `-L 1` as in `cat list | xargs -L 1 -p touch`, right?

Answer (score 24):

Put an `echo` in front of the command to run?

```
$ echo a b c d e | xargs -n2 echo rm
rm a b
rm c d
rm e
```

Comment: (This, is of course only a simple solution that works in trivial cases. The output will be ambiguous if the parameters contain spaces or control characters. We'd need some dedicated tool to unambiguously print the parameters it receives.)

Comment: What about if you're trying to dry-run `echo`? :)

Comment: This isn't the answer to the question, and it shouldn't be the accepted one. This answer show an example of using 'xargs' on the 'echo' command. The OP wants to run 'xargs' on an arbitrary command, but also show the computed command which is about to be fired. The correct answer is below, by Kevin Hencke, about the -t and -p flags.

Comment: @Gabriel, of course it's an answer to the question. It's not a complete answer, of course, more like an idea (which is somewhat hinted at by the question mark, and the comment noting that there are limitations). But an answer it is, and it's up to every one else to decide how to vote on it. Not that there seem to have been many alternatives in, oh, one and a half _years_.

Comment: @Gabriel, note that the question mentioned "[an] option that will show you what they're going to do **without doing it**." -- I can't really see how `--verbose` and `--interactive` could be bent to do that, unless someone can figure out a way to pipe the output of `yes n` to `xargs --interactive` (I tried and failed). Also, `--verbose` also has the issue that its output is ambiguous, e.g. `echo '"a b" c' | xargs --verbose rm` prints `rm a b c`, the same as `echo 'a b c' | xargs --verbose rm` prints, even though the commands are very much not the same.

Comment: @Gabriel, but honestly, I wish there was a better answer. I'll be happy to edit this to point to one when e.g. `xargs` implements a working `--dry-run` itself.

Answer (score 2):

## Inspect Arguments with Your Favorite Programming Langauges

Insert any of the following commands between`xargs` and commands you want to execute.

1. `ruby -e 'p ARGV'`
2. `node -e 'console.log(process.argv)'`
3. `python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv'`

In this answer, I would use `ruby -e 'p ARGV'` for every example.

## Usage

Let's say you want to debug the script:

```bsh
echo 1 2 3 4 | xargs echo
```

To debug, put `ruby -e 'p ARGV'` before `echo`:

```bsh
echo 1 2 3 4 | xargs ruby -e 'p ARGV' echo
```

```
["echo", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

As we can see, it's very clear that `echo` received 2 arguments.

Here is another example using `-I`:

```bsh
echo 1 2 3 4 | xargs -I@ ruby -e 'p ARGV' echo @
```

```
["echo", "1 2 3 4"]
```

Now we know `echo` received only one argument.

## Why not `xargs -t -p`?

Because `-t` and `-p` are really ambiguous when there are white spaces in command arguments, for example:

```bsh
printf 'hello world\0goodbye world' | xargs -0 -t echo
```

```
echo hello world goodbye world
hello world goodbye world
```

When looking at `echo hello world goodbye world`, it's hard to tell whether `echo` received 2 or 4 arguments.

By using the solution, it's easy to understand how `xargs` treats each arguments:

```bsh
printf 'hello world\0goodbye world' | xargs -0 ruby -e 'p ARGV' echo
```

```
["echo", "hello world", "goodbye world"]
```