# How do I loop over the lines in STDIN and run a shell command?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, xargs

I'd like to run a shell command on each line taken from STDIN.

In this case, I'd like to run `xargs mv`. For example, given two lines:

```
mfoo foo
mbar bar
```

I'd like to run:

```
xargs mv mfoo foo
xargs mv mbar bar
```

I've tried the following strategies with `ruby`, `awk`, and `xargs`. However, I'm doing it wrong:

Just `xargs`:

```
$ echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | xargs mv
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Through `awk`:

```
$ echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | awk '{ system("xargs $0") }'
```

Through `ruby`:

```
$ echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | ruby -ne '`xargs mv`'
$ ls
cat  foo  mbar mbaz
```

I have some questions:

- How do I do what I'm trying to do?
- What is wrong with each of my attempts?
- Is there a better way to "think about" what I'm trying to do?

I'm especially confused that my `xargs` attempt isn't working because the following works:

```
$ echo "foo\nbar" | xargs touch
$ ls
bar foo
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `xargs`? Try just running `mv` instead of `xargs` in your AWK and Ruby scripts. Then ponder what happens with filenames containing “special” characters (space…).

Comment: What is it that you're wanting `xargs` to give you?

Comment: That is, what do you want to happen by getting `xargs mv mfoo foo` and `xargs mv mbar bar` to run?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I was thinking it might rename the files.

Comment: I think what’s surprising is that you’re persisting in attempting to build an incorrect solution to your problem. It might be a worthwhile learning exercise, I can’t judge that. Have you read the `xargs` documentation?

Comment: `xargs mv mfoo foo` will wait for input and run `mv mfoo foo $x_1 $x_2 $x_3...` for every line `$x_n` of input it gets. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @StephenKitt my intent wasn't too continue with my other question, (which is why it isn't a comment). My intent was to learn about running shell commands on each line of input taken from stdin and use this as a specific example. Is it a bad strategy? Can you recommend a way I can improve the question? Honestly, so far I've learned a lot from this question, so it doesn't seem bad for me. On my end a question that illustrates a fundamental lack of understanding of the "right" way to do something seems to me like a great opportunity to explain the "right" way to do it.

Comment: `echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | awk '{ system("xargs mv " $0) }'` ought to generate the xargs commands you requested.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it's doesn't fail but it also doesn't successfully rename the files for me.

Comment: I found out why! `xargs` needs to have the args piped into it. The following will work: `echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | awk '{ system("mv " $0) }'` notice the absence of `xargs`

Comment: We can’t guess what your intent was. We often get chains of questions here which seem to pursue bad ideas, more often that questions from people genuinely trying to understand what’s going on. Re your “I found out why” just above, did you see my very first comment?

Comment: I'm reading the awk programming language and the UNIX programming environment, I'm really excited about it and eager to learn more, I love how Brian uses specific examples to articulate more general concepts and has a fun, humble and non grouchy attitude. So I'm also asking specific questions. Do you think my questions are bad? How could they be improved if you do? Your comments are cryptic and confusing. If you're answering questions every day and getting burned out that makes sense, if you have something specific you think I can improve upon I'm happy to hear it also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | xargs mv
```

With `xargs` you should use the `-t` option to see what's going on. So in your above case if we were to invoke `xargs` with `-t`, what do we see:

`mv mbar bar mbaz baz`

So obviously it's not correct. What happened was that `xargs` like a hungry crocodile, ate all the args fed to it via the pipe by `echo`. So you need a way to limit the release of arguments to the croc. And since you requested on a per-line basis, then what you need is the `-l` or the `-L` for POSIX option.

```
echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | xargs -l -t mv
```

POSIX-ly way:

```
echo "mbar bar\nmbaz baz" | xargs -L 1 -t mv

mv mbar bar
mv mbaz baz
```

And this is what you wanted.
H.T.H

Comment: Bravo! Success on `bsd xargs` on macOS `10.12.3`. From the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html): `-L _number_: Call utility for every number lines read.`

Comment: You can also combine -p with -t and xargs will prompt user for confirmation before execution of each command according to man pages.

Comment: Do you know if there is another way to dry-run with the `-t` option? I've tried a strategy mentioned in [another answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/300097/173557) by using `echo` but it doesn't work if you're trying to dry-run `echo` itself :)

Comment: @mbigras Remove the `-t` when using `echo`. And since `echo` is harmless so in a way it's its own `dry-run` :-) Or you may remove `echo` as well then `xargs` will list the arguments in the order it ate.

Comment: Haha, of course, was trying too many things :) That works for me. Also as mentioned in your other answer. If you don't mind adding a section on POSIX will be happy to accept your answer!

Comment: Again, you should only do this if you don’t care about your data.

Comment: @StephenKitt I would like to follow the case that this xargs exercise will break. I created a file with space in name: `touch "my foo"`. Then i tried the solution advised in this answer with proper quoting: `echo "mbar bar\n'my foo' foo" | xargs -l -t mv` and works ok. Offcourse without quoting  around `my foo` the `mv` breaks. Is that the case you talk about?

Comment: @George amongst others, yes. You’d need to handle any special character that’s allowed in a filename (including single and double quotes, newlines...). The `for` loop using shell globbing works fine, getting all that right with `xargs` is a lot harder (unless you can use the null character as a separator throughout).

Comment: @Stephen OK - Now thing are more clear why this `xargs mv` is not a good idea to handle real files. Every special char needs special treatment to ensure the expected results, something that we do not need to worry using globbing methods or null separation techniques

Answer (score 2):

You can go this way:

```
echo -e "foo bar\ndoo dar" | xargs -n 2 mv
```

To read from file:

```
cat lines.txt | xargs -n 2 mv
```

or

```
xargs -a lines.txt -n 2 mv
```

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` might not behave how you expect. See @MichaelHomer's comment to this question:

> `xargs mv mfoo foo` will wait for input and run mv `mfoo foo $x_1 $x_2 $x_3...` for every line `$x_n` of input it gets. @MichaelHomer

This can be confirmed by reading the [`xargs` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html):

> DESCRIPTION
>        The xargs utility reads space, tab, newline and end-of-file delimited strings from the standard input
>        and executes utility with the strings as arguments.

In practice, it seems like `xargs` will ignore newlines when feeding args to the command line utility given as it's first arg. For example, notice what happens to the newline:

```
$ echo "foo bar\ncat dog"
foo bar
cat dog
$ echo "foo bar\ncat dog" | xargs echo
foo bar cat dog
```

This behavior can be controlled with the [`-n` flag](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html):

> -n number
>
> Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for
>   each invocation of utility.

Going back to the previous example if we wanted `xargs` take only 2 args then quit then we can use [@ddnomad's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358002/173557):

```
$ echo "foo bar\ncat dog" | xargs -n 2 echo
foo bar
cat dog
```

Also, as shown in the comments in Rakesh Sharma's answer, on BSD `xargs` you can specify the number of lines to be read with the `-L` flag. From the man page:

> -L number
>
> Call utility for every number lines read.  If EOF is reached and
>   fewer lines have been read than number then utility will be     called
>   with the available lines.

Equally helpful for testing is the `-t` switch:

Revisiting our example, both of the followings will work; however, the second example is better because it's what was intending in this case:

```
$ echo "foo bar\ncat dog" | xargs -n 2 echo
foo bar
cat dog
$ echo "foo bar\ncat dog" | xargs -L 1 echo
foo bar
cat dog
```

Note from the man page:

> The -L and -n options are mutually exclusive; the last one given will be used.

Comment: This seems to me to be a summary of the existing answers; you *may* self-answer, but please make sure you're adding something new.

Comment: Do any of the other answers include references to the manual and notes for avoiding confusion?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution that does not use xargs.
Define this function:

```
$ mv2() { while (($# >1 )); do echo mv "$1" "$2"; shift 2; done; }
```

Then, just call it with the list of filenames needed (no newlines required):

```
$ mv2 mbar bar mbaz baz
mv mbar bar
mv mbaz baz
```

Remove the echo to make the function really work.